# Allow mouse hover only on an iframe (no clicking)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm looking to lock down and iframe that I currently have.

I want it so that anyone can hover over it and the pointer finger will appear, but it just disables all abilities to click within it. I've tried using the `pointer-events: none;` css option but that disables everything.

I cannot seem to find anywhere online that would make this possible with an iframe, any ideas?

Comment: Functionality is en/disabled with JavaScript, not CSS. If the frame is showing a page on the same domain, or on a domain you control, you can achieve this with JS. If not, you can't. The best you could do is overlay a transparent DIV on top of the frame to prevent clicking.

Comment: I don't have access to the javascript - but yeah I think that may be what I have to end up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be helpfull for you :

```
<div title="Your title Here" style="pointer-events: none !important;  cursor: pointer;">
    <iframe id="clock1" src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" width="110" height="110" 
            style="pointer-events: none !important;  cursor: pointer;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't @JordanWells say he already tried CSS `pointer-events: none` but it didn't suit his needs?

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution could be to use a div as a catcher on top of you iframe which has CSS property `cursor: pointer;`, this will emulate the pointer effect and you will block all interactions within the iframe.

```css
#catcher {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="catcher">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%">
</iframe>
<div>
```

Comment: Should have probably explained but that would work great and all but the reason I want them to be able to hover is because of graphs in the iframe , they're somewhat interactive (you can drag them around, click on them, resize them etc.) but I don't want any of that. I just want to be able to hover over different data points but no be able to clic if possible.